# Load external JavaScript(-files) with a user key

Tags: javascript, cryptography, security

I'd like to provide a JavaScript Service (if you know Google Maps you know what I'm talking about) which is accessible by passing a user key as parameter.

Example (JavaScript):

```
loadScript("http://www.mypage.org/service/myscript.js?userkey=ADF34fSDF3432FSD34324", function () { /* on loaded. */ });
```

As you can see, the *user key* is the credential to access the script on behalf of a registered user. Google Maps uses such pattern.

My questions:

- What exactly is the 'user key'?
- How to prevent, that another webdeveloper (reading my code) uses my key?
- I know, that Google (for Google Maps) binds the key somehow to the users domain... but JavaScript is executed in the clients browser. Any suggestions?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What exactly is the 'user key'?

Is the thing you are thinking of - user identifier in the google system.

> How to prevent, that another webdeveloper (reading my code) uses my
>   key

In real life there is no way to secure this code. If someone will really want to steal it - he will do.

> I know, that Google (for Google Maps) binds the key somehow to the
>   users domain... but JavaScript is executed in the clients browser. Any
>   suggestions?

Browser request contains a lot of information items and one of them is the domain which requested the file. Google checks if the key matches to the domain and gives the file.

thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. According to the last question: I know there are some client header like "referer" or something, but that's all stuff i can spoof. Isn't there a more complex mechanism behind it, like 'challange and response'?

Comment: The problem is that this id is opened, everyone can see it just by checking source code of your html page. And yes, I guess it is easy to spoof.